# How can I find a message send in a specific Channel from the bot? [discord.js]

Tags: javascript, bots, discord, discord.js

I want to get the last send message from the bot in a channel. I use the newest version of discord.js(12.2.0).

Answer (score 0):

Use the [discord.js](http://discord.js.org) documentation:

This can help you
[Discord.js TextChannel -> Last Message](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/TextChannel?scrollTo=lastMessage)